# How to assign different colours to different points of a dotchart in R?

Tags: r, plot

I am new to R programming and I am trying to analyse a data set.

I have a set of data with 3 columns. They are labelled Gender(Male/Female), Income(integers), and Education(Name of college that the subject graduated from).

I want to plot a dotchart where the y axis is Education(Name of college) and x axis is the the income. After which, I want to order the data according to their individual income and assign colours to these points according to their genders - for example, blue for Males and red for Females.

I have done the following:

```
data <- read.delim("my_data.txt")
x <- data[order(data$Income),] #sort by income
dotchart(x$Income,x$Education,cex=0.6, main ="Income of Students", xlab = "Income in Dollars ($)")
```

My question is, how do I then assign a different colour to these points according to their gender? And after which, how do I create a legend for reference?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the default `pch=21`, you specify the color using `bg`

```
dotchart(x$Income,x$Education,cex=0.6, bg=rainbow(2)[x$Gender],
    main ="Income of Students", xlab = "Income in Dollars ($)")
legend("topright", legend=levels(x$Gender), pch=21, bg=rainbow(2))
```